# some images don't work on Webview React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm loading a site through webview, but some images don't work, I went to analyze and saw that the images that don't work the `attr` changed from `src` to `data-src`. the problem is that on my site this is not so.

[image]

```
<WebView
    onLoad={() => setLoading(false)}
    source={{ uri: url || `${ENV.WEBVIEW_URL}${route}` }}
    style={{
        width,
        display: loading ? 'none' : 'flex',
        backgroundColor: theme.base.background,
    }}
    injectedJavaScriptBeforeContentLoaded={myInjectedJsBeforeContentLoaded}
    onMessage={(event) =>
        onMessage ? onMessage(JSON.parse(event.nativeEvent.data)) : {}
    }
    ref={webviewRef}
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a workaround using the `injectJavascript` property:

```js
const changeDataSrcJavascript = `
   var imageElements = document.querySelectorAll('img');
    
   imageElements.forEach(c=> c.setAttribute('src', c.getAttribute('data-src')));
`;

  return (
    <WebView
      injectedJavaScript={changeDataSrcJavascript}
      ...
    />
  );
```

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work

Comment: @RafaelAugusto please share the URI link used